# What is the difference between the pronunciation of "horse" and "whores"?

Tags: pronunciation

Cambridge dictionary lists the pronunciation of horse as /hɔːrs/ and that of whore as /hɔːr/.
What exactly is the way to pronounce both of them?

[A clip from The Big Bang Theory "get back on the horse"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jobvVaekOKA)

Comment: But if the pronunciation of _whore_ is /hɔːr/, then the pronunciation of  _whores_ is /hɔːrz/, since the plural suffix is pronounced /z/ after /r/. So one is  /hɔːrs/ and the other is /hɔːrz/. Can you tell the difference?

Comment: There is tremendous and interesting answer to this in the linked original  written by Araucaria... key quote 'Here is what is really happening when a native speaker hears the word whores and why they can differentiate it from the word horse. Unvoiced consonants have an effect on preceding vowels, whereby they cause them to become much shorter.'  go read it!